# Is a clear distinction made between signs and operators?

Tags: arithmetic-operations, negative-numbers

[This question about FOIL](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/16561/why-in-the-foil-method-the-terms-are-taken-with-their-signs), comments and answers made me think about the two roles of $-$: as a sign and as an operator. This struck me because the title

### "Why in the FOIL Method the terms are taken with their signs?"

seems odd to me, because in the example given, $$(x+2)(x-3),$$ there are no signs, just one subtraction operator. To get a sign appear, one first would have to convert to $$(x+2)(x+(\color{red}{-}3))$$ to get the red minus sign.

In Germany, we have "Vorzeichen" (sign, literally "pre sign") and "Rechenzeichen" (operator, literally "calculation sign") and I think a similar distiction can be made in english with sign and operator, but I get the impression that the use is rather sloppy.

---

Question:

When first teaching negative numbers, is a clear distinction between the two roles of $-$ made?

Comment: Related: [Might it be helpful for students to have different symbols for subtraction (-) and negation ( _ )?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/13295)

Comment: Explaining to students that $a -b = a+ (-b) = a + (-1)\cdot b$ helps them to understand subtraction  as addition of a negative number (where a negative number (-b) represents operation on a number (b) by -1).  So one can translate easily between the  "two" roles you speak of.

Comment: For what it's worth, on at least some calculators there actually is a separate button for $\pm$ versus subtraction.

Answer (score 5):

It can definitely be confusing, and a clear distinction should be made when teaching. It's not always made, and students can in fact remain lost for a long time. I've seen students who thought $1 \cdot (-1) = 0$, unsure of the role of $"\cdot"$, $"-"$, and parentheses.

As far as symbol, it's not too confusing if when teaching you use parentheses, e.g. "$(-5)$", and call it "negative five" (rather than "minus five"). When students are ready, explain that it's OK to omit parentheses when there is no confusion.

Here's how [Beast Academy](https://beastacademy.com/books) approaches it (I am not involved in it, but like the books). First they introduce negative numbers, and it's only after some practice that they get to adding a negative number, and later yet to subtracting:

1. Explain negative numbers on the number line, explaining that $-4$ is read "negative four", etc.
2. Comparing negative numbers, e.g. $-15 < -7$
3. Adding on the number line, e.g. "To add 3, we move 3 units to the right", with example of $5+3$ and then $-5+3$.
4. But if $-5 + 3$ is $-2$, then it nust be that "3 plus -5 also equals -2", but how does that work on the number line?
5. To add a negative number, we move left, and write it as $3 + (-5) = -2$.
6. There is a whole separate section to remind students of subtraction: on the number line, we go left to subtract a number, e.g. with $9 - 5$.
7. We can use the same method to subtract e.g. $5 - 9$.
8. Another way to solve $5-9$, we can find the number to add to 9 to get 5. Since $(-4) + 9 = 5$, it must be that $5-9=-4$.

So that's how you can explain why $3 + (-5)$ is the same as $3 - 5$. (Here you can draw the students attention to the choice of the symbol for "subtraction" and for "negatives" -- it's the same symbol, because the two concepts are in fact closely connected.) Then there is a whole other section about subtracting a negative.

Comment: Thanks. No relation, I just have and like the books.